# Conversion between const void* to char

Tags: c++

How can I convert between `const void*` to `char`?

Using C++ casts only.

```
void foo( const void* data)
{
   char bar = static_cast<char>(data); // error: invalid static_cast from type 'const void*' to type 'char'
   printf( "foo: %d\n", bar);
}
```

Comment: `char bar = reinterpret_cast<char>(data);` but I doubt that it's what you want... I mean: why on earth would you want to cast a `void*` to `char`?

Comment: I've tried using reinterpret_cast and I got also the error: cast from 'const void*' to 'char' loses precision

Comment: And that's why you hardly want that... May be what you want is `static_cast<char*>(data)`?

Comment: Maybe you want this `char bar = *static_cast< char* >( data );`.

Comment: yes! I was missing the pointer before the static_cast! Thanks you both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@aslg gave the answer on the comments:

```
char bar = *static_cast< char* >( data );
```

Answer (score -1):

**Code to convert void* to char:**

char* temp = (char*)data;

char bar = *temp;

Comment: The question is tagged C++. C++ named casts should be preferred over C-style casts because they're more restrictive (each named cast is limited in the kind of conversions allowed) and because they're easier to spot when reading the code. What you want is `char bar = *static_cast<char*>(data);`

Comment: Thanks, I am new to this forum, I will tags in mind when I answer next time.